# SQL Result to multiple array

Tags: sql

MY SQL returns the following array...

| id | staff | province |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ben | Ontario |
| 2 | Ben | Quebec |
| 3 | John | Manitoba |
| 4 | John | Saskatchewan |
| 6 | Kitty | Alberta |
| 7 | Kitty | Nova Scotia |

I would like to have the record displayed like this...

| staff | province |
| --- | --- |
| Ben | Ontario, Quebec |
| John | Quebec, Manitoba, Saskatchewan |
| Kitty | Alberta, Nova Scotia |

what approach should I use to approach this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS in order to get answers that work for you. The string aggregation function you are looking for can be `LISTAGG`, `STRING_AGG`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, or yet another function depending on which DBMS you are working with. This is not about arrays either, by the way. A SQL query result is a *table*. Your desired result column `province` looks like a string. If your DBMS supports arrays, it can be an array and the function might then be `ARRAY_AGG` or the like.

Comment: You have got two answers. Both assume you are using MySQL for unknownn reasons. You can see that they both say you must aggregate your data by staff using `GROUP BY staff`. This is something you should already know, because this is a very basic concept in SQL. So it would have been good, had you mentioned that you know how to write an aggregation query, but don't know which method to use to get the aggregated string or array. But then, why didn't you just look up the docs for your DBMS? It is a bit strange that you have not been able to find the solution yourself. Did you even try?

Comment: Thank you Thorsten Kettner, yes, i am referring to MySQL, and I must say, I only know very little SQL. So I did not know you can get SQL to do something like this. I thought I had to get the table out from MySQL, and then use for-loop in php to get the desired output. That's why i tagged as Array.
FYI, I tried it already using PHP and for-loop, but i suspect there is a faster way to approach a problem like this. instead of the 2O^2 Operation I am currently using. My database gets to 300 row and browser is slow already.

Comment: but thank you so much for your info, I will defiantly look up string aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be better to post the tables as well for clearer context.

You can use Aggregate functions and Grouping to help doing this. A GROUP BY to group the rows by `staff` column, then use GROUP_CONCAT() to concatenate `province` values in one string.

A reference of how you want it to be, unsure what table you are using or if there are any other factors but you can adapt as needed.

```
SELECT staff, GROUP_CONCAT(province SEPARATOR ', ') as province
FROM table_name
GROUP BY staff;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, this is a way simpler solution that I was thinking.